# How would I go about figuring out which set is equal to A∖(B∖C)?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

How would I go about figuring which set between C∖(A∪B), (B∖A)∪(C∖A), (A∖C)∪(B∖C) and (A∖B)∪(A∩C) is equivalent to A∖(B∖C)? I've already attempted to create a venn diagram for all of these sets however none of them were equivalent to A∖(B∖C) leaving me confused.

Comment: Easy way to eliminate the other options is to take $B=C$ then the first $3$ options are not equal to $A$ so the 4th is the only possibility.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\in A\backslash(B\backslash C)\iff$$

$$x\in A \wedge x\notin (B\backslash C)\iff$$

$$x\in A \wedge (x\notin B \vee x\in C)\iff$$

$$(x\in A\wedge x\notin B) \vee (x\in A\wedge x\in C)\iff$$

$$x\in (A\backslash B) \vee x\in A\cap C \iff$$

$$x\in (A\backslash B ) \cup A\cap C$$

thus
$$A\backslash (B\backslash C)=(A\backslash B) \cup ( A\cap C)$$

So, the last answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth option works. The others don't.

You got 4 possible answers. $C\backslash (A\cup B)$,
$(B\backslash A)\cup (C\backslash A)$, $(A\backslash C)\cup (B\backslash C)$ and $(A\backslash B)\cup (A\cap C)$ and you want to see which one is $S=A\backslash (B\backslash C)$. The set $S$ is clearly a subset of $A$. So the first three options don't work. The fourth option works . Indeed, if $x$ is in $A\backslash B$ then $x$ is in $S$ and if $x\in A\cap C$, then $x\in S$. So $(A\backslash B)\cup (A\cap C)\subseteq S$. Now if $x\in S$ then it is in $A$. If it  is not in $A\backslash B$, then it is in $A\cap B$. But it is not in $B\backslash C$. So it must be in $A\cap C$. So $S\subseteq (A\backslash B)\cup (A\cap C)$.